# Symfony, PHPExcel not accepting date array from database?

Tags: php, excel, symfony

I'm having problems outputting an excel with its date object. I'm using PHPExcel on Symfony. I performed an SQL that grabs data from the database in my Symfony controller. Then I did a for loop to iterate through each rows of data. However when I added in the value of a date, it gives me an error:

`FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array in ...\Symfony\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php line 86`

Here is my code:

```
$excel = new PHPExcel();

$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 // ..etc

for($results as $result) {
   // codes..
   ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $result['date'])

}
```

It's not allowing me to output the excel because of this. Should I be converting it to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution through looping through the cell with the date values and setting it as date by number format:

```
$excel = new PHPExcel();

$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// ..etc

$i = 3;
for($results as $result) {

  $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$i)
          ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);

  $date = \PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($result['date']);

  // codes..
    ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $result['date'])
}
```